# “bash read command” in nodejs

Tags: node.js, git, githooks

I wanna write a git hook scripts with nodejs which I'm good at. In bash files, I can get params like this:

`#!/bin/bash
read local_ref local_sha remote_ref remote_sha`

Is there any same command in nodejs?

`#!/usr/bin/env node
"bash read function in nodejs"`

Comment: a search for "nodejs user input" returns many options

Comment: @Adil I tried, but get empty value of params.

Comment: did pass the correct path of git

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-git

Comment: :( node-cmd work for me you can try simple-git

Comment: @Adil Can u get the correct output of $1 param in git hook pre-push file?

Comment: @Allen i tried node-cmd which work like boom

Answer (score 2):

here are some module which help u to write command

> node-cmd

Simple commandline/terminal interface to allow you to run cli or bash style commands as if you were in the terminal.

> shelljs

ShellJS is a portable (Windows/Linux/OS X) implementation of Unix shell commands on top of the Node.js API. You can use it to eliminate your shell script's dependency on Unix while still keeping its familiar and powerful commands. You can also install it globally so you can run it from outside Node projects - say goodbye to those gnarly Bash scripts!

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cmd

https://www.npmjs.com/package/shelljs

have a look at this code may help u

`var cmd=require('node-cmd');`

```
    cmd.get(
        git clone https://github.com/RIAEvangelist/node-cmd.git
        cd node-cmd
        ls
    ,
    function(data){
        console.log('the node-cmd cloned dir contains these files :\n\n',data)
    }
);
```

> have look on this module

```
// starting a new repo 
require('simple-git')()
     .init()
     .add('./*')
     .commit("first commit!")
     .addRemote('origin', 'https://github.com/user/repo.git')
     .push('origin', 'master');

// push with -u 
require('simple-git')()
     .add('./*')
     .commit("first commit!")
     .addRemote('origin', 'some-repo-url')
     .push(['-u', 'origin', 'master'], function () {
        // done. 
     });
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-git